# Populate rows in SQL based on a value and a key

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

Current Dataset- Has dates, ID and Values

```
ID | Value | Date 
--------------------
X  | 1.1       |  2020/01/14
X  | 2.1       |  2020/01/15
Y  | 0.9       |  2020/01/11
X  | 3.2       |  2020/01/18
Y  | 2.4       |  2020/01/14
```

`Expected Result - Looking for standard SQL script that will help me to Populate missing dates and carry/roll/copy IDs and Values for given ID. (preferably Bigquery or Spark SQL)

Expected Result

```
   ID | Value | Date 
   --------------------
  X  | 1.1       |  2020/01/14
  X  | 2.1       |  2020/01/15
  X  | 2.1       |  2020/01/16
  X  | 2.1       |  2020/01/17
  X  | 3.2       |  2020/01/18
  Y  | 0.9       |  2020/01/11
  Y  | 0.9       |  2020/01/12
  Y  | 0.9       |  2020/01/13
  Y  | 2.4       |  2020/01/14
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BigQuery, you can use `generate_date_array()` and aggregation to get the rows:

```
select i.id, the_date, t.value
from (select id, min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date
      from t
      group by id
     ) i cross join
     unnest(generate_date_array(min_date, max_date)) the_date left join
     t
     on t.id = i.id and g.date = the_date;
```

You can fill in the values in various ways.  Your data seems to be increasing, so a cumulative max would work:

```
select i.id, the_date,
       max(t.value) over (partition by i.id order by the_date) as value
from (select id, min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date
      from t
      group by id
     ) i cross join
     unnest(generate_date_array(min_date, max_date)) the_date left join
     t
     on t.id = i.id and g.date = the_date;
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
coalesce(value,
         last_value(value ignore nulls) over (partition by i.id order by thedate)
        ) as value
```